# Should I keep Socket connection open

Tags: c#, sockets

i have an web app. it opens a socket to a server. sends a message and waits for a response. The user may then perform another socket request to the server or may give it 5, 10, 15 mins(etc) and then send another message to the server.  Or may close the web app.

Should i close the socket after each send/receive request or keep it open?

Thanks

Comment: If it's not being utilized, close it.....

Comment: Are you talking about a browser client that talks to the web-server via web-sockets, or do you mean that the web-server talks via a socket to a separate server? It matters.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. i don't use web sockets. i use tcp sockets.  everything is all on the same server.

Comment: hi Darren.  thanks your reply.  my biggest concern is whether there is an overhead on reconnecting on every request.

Comment: I think the best way to resolve this problem is using http (post/get) requests in stead of using a websocket/socket. In my opinion a websocket/socket is used for a single request with multiple answers. Your model has one answer for each request.

Comment: hi Bob, thanks for taking the time to reply.  for me to use that I would have to allow my winforms app to act as a http server would i not?  is that easy to do and should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close socket and make new connection if some addition delay (connect time is about round trip time (ping time)) is not a problem. If you will use SSL in the future it is better to keep session alive because the SSL connection establish much more difficult from the CPU resource point of view. Consider SO_KEEPALIVE socket option for permanent connections.